# answers getting error while 3D array declare in C

Tags: arrays, c, dev-c++

I am having an error since I needed to turn a 2d array into a 3d array. I understand this because if I put the array assignment in comment, I no longer have the problem. I also send here the part of the code where I assign the 3d array.

```
    consulta agendaMedicos[50][50][50]; 
    consulta agendaEnfermeiros[50][50][50];
```

I don't think it's relevant but the struct I use is this:

```
typedef struct Consulta {

    char nomeUtente[70];
    int numSNS;
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
    int horasInicio;
    int minutosInicio;
    int horasFim;
    int minutosFim;

} consulta;
```

Here is an example of how I send the array to a new function

```
void novaConsulta(int *nAgendasMedico, consulta agendaMedicos[][50][50], int membroEscolhido, int clinicaSelecionada)
```

Here my only function :

```
void novaConsulta(int *nAgendasMedico, consulta agendaMedicos[][50][50], int membroEscolhido, int clinicaSelecionada)
{
    
    do 
    {
                
        puts("Insira o dia:");
        scanf("%d", &agendaMedicos[nAgendasMedico[membroEscolhido]][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].dia);
        system("cls");
                
    }while (agendaMedicos[nAgendasMedico[membroEscolhido]][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].dia < 0 || agendaMedicos[nAgendasMedico[membroEscolhido]][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].dia > 31);
    
    printf("%d", agendaMedicos[nAgendasMedico[membroEscolhido]][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].dia);
    
}
```

Here my main code :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    int membroEscolhido = 1, clinicaSelecionada = 0;
    
    int nAgendasMedico[50];
    
    consulta agendaMedicos[50][50][50]; 
    consulta agendaEnfermeiros[50][50][50];
    
    nAgendasMedico[membroEscolhido] = 0;
    
    novaConsulta(nAgendasMedico, agendaMedicos, membroEscolhido, clinicaSelecionada);
    
    nAgendasMedico[membroEscolhido]++;
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the program, no error appears, what happens is that the program closes after a while, as in the image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR1Qw.png)

There is my  minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */



typedef struct Consulta {

    char nomeUtente[70];
    int numSNS;
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
    int horasInicio;
    int minutosInicio;
    int horasFim;
    int minutosFim;

} consulta;

void novaConsulta(int *nAgendasMedico, consulta agendaMedicos[][50][50], int membroEscolhido, int clinicaSelecionada);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    int membroEscolhido = 1, clinicaSelecionada = 0;
    
    int nAgendasMedico[50];
    
    consulta agendaMedicos[50][50][50]; 
    consulta agendaEnfermeiros[50][50][50];
    
    nAgendasMedico[membroEscolhido] = 0;
    
    novaConsulta(nAgendasMedico, agendaMedicos, membroEscolhido, clinicaSelecionada);
    
    nAgendasMedico[membroEscolhido]++;
    
    return 0;
}

void novaConsulta(int *nAgendasMedico, consulta agendaMedicos[][50][50], int membroEscolhido, int clinicaSelecionada)
{
    
    do 
    {
                
        puts("Insira o dia:");
        scanf("%d", &agendaMedicos[nAgendasMedico[membroEscolhido]][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].dia);
        system("cls");
                
    }while (agendaMedicos[nAgendasMedico[membroEscolhido]][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].dia < 0 || agendaMedicos[nAgendasMedico[membroEscolhido]][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].dia > 31);
    
    printf("%d", agendaMedicos[nAgendasMedico[membroEscolhido]][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].dia);
    
}
```

My development program is DevC++ an C language.
Thank you all

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I'm sorry, I managed to create this new example with the same problem. I hope it becomes more perespectible now. Thanks in advance

Comment: What input do you give it?

Comment: I don't write anything, the program takes some time to think and goes down without me pressing anything

Comment: Your array has 125k elements of approx 90 bytes each, you may be overflowing the stack. Again, please extract a [mcve] first, which is one file that can be compiled and executed without any changes. [edit] your question to include that info, not separate snippets. Also, I haven't looked at that image, but generally quoting the text is better.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you are able to be right about the memory problem. However from what I read and realized about what a minimal reproducible example is, I think there is an example. In this case, just copy and paste into your development program. If I'm wrong, please let me know

Comment: compiling+linking+executing results is a seg fault event 'immediately' after the `main()` signature.  TO correct that problem, either move these statements: `consulta agendaMedicos[50][50][50];` and `consulta agendaEnfermeiros[50][50][50];` to file global space or use `malloc()` to allocate the needed space.  see my answer for an example

Comment: Be aware you reserved stack space is over 25M for just the two arrays shown (minimum with no padding). That exceeds the largest default stack size by a factor of 6 (by more than a factor of 25 on Windows). You will need to allocate storage (or uses `static` storage or heaven forbid make the arrays global)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moving the 3d arrays from the stack (approx 11.2 million bytes each) to the file global space results in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// much more flexible to separate definition of the struct
// from a 'typedef' for that struct

struct Consulta 
{
    char nomeUtente[70];
    int numSNS;
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
    int horasInicio;
    int minutosInicio;
    int horasFim;
    int minutosFim;
};

typedef struct Consulta consulta;


consulta agendaMedicos[50][50][50]; // <- in file global space


void novaConsulta(int *nAgendasMedico, consulta agendaMedicos[][50][50], int membroEscolhido, int clinicaSelecionada)
{  
    do 
    {                
        puts("Insira o dia:");
        scanf("%d", &agendaMedicos[nAgendasMedico[membroEscolhido]][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].dia);
        //system("cls");             
    }while (agendaMedicos[nAgendasMedico[membroEscolhido]][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].dia < 0 || agendaMedicos[nAgendasMedico[membroEscolhido]][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].dia > 31);
    
    printf("%d", agendaMedicos[nAgendasMedico[membroEscolhido]][membroEscolhido][clinicaSelecionada].dia);    
}

// notice the correction to the `main()` signature
// so compiler does not output 2 warning messages
// about unused parameters

int main( void )   
{
    int membroEscolhido = 1;
    int clinicaSelecionada = 0;
    
    int nAgendasMedico[50];
    

    //consulta agendaEnfermeiros[50][50][50]; // moved to file global space
    
    nAgendasMedico[membroEscolhido] = 0;
    
    novaConsulta(nAgendasMedico, agendaMedicos, membroEscolhido, clinicaSelecionada);
    
    nAgendasMedico[membroEscolhido]++;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nit, I got `12.75M` each (ignoring padding) E.g. `102 * 50 * 50 * 50`. Allocation or `static` should rank before global in the list of choices.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin,  when each data structure (3d array) is over 10million bytes it does not really matter +/- a million bytes And my objective was to indicate the problem and a possible fix, not every possible problem and associated fix and the specific size depends on the underlying hard ware architecture. (for instance my x86-64 architecture is actually going to use nearly twice the memory of a x86

Comment: No worries, that's why I labeled the comment a "Nit" (de minimis)

Comment: Thank you everyone, I put the variable in the in file global space. And that solve'it